# Missing with a splash weapon II - Target against a wall / water / pit

Tags: pathfinder-1e, combat, ranged-attack, alchemist, throwing-things

(This is kind of a follow-up to [Missing with a splash weapon](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/141025/missing-with-a-splash-weapon))

### Situation

There is an alchemist (or other splash weapon user) "T", throwing her splash weapon at a target "X" that is within T's weapon's first range increment - so if T misses, her weapon will impact one square off the original target (see linked question for details to that)

The twist here is:
Target is standing with its back against

1. a wall
2. a river / the sea / water
3. a pit / a precipice of some sort

[image: [2]]

### Question

If the thrower T misses, and rolls 1,2,3 on her miss roll, what will happen?

1. Wall: Will the squares 7,6 and 5 be impacted by splash damage? Which squares will suffer splash damage?
2. Water: Will there be splash damage at all, i.e. will the surface of the water be hard enough to trigger the explosion?
3. Pit: Will there be splash damage at all, since technically the splash weapon will tumble out of sight?

### Bonus Questions

1. But there are holes in the wall
2. But the water is frozen
3. But the pit is exactly 5 foot deep

I think this boils down to wether you consider splash weapons to be "explode-on-impact". At least for Alchemists Bombs, which are (Su) - Supernatural you could argue that they don't just explode on a mechanical-physical basis, but the Alchemist wills it into exploding (?)

Would love to hear your takes on that.

Greetings

Comment: This feels like a test.

Comment: @ShadowKras I am sorry if the question is presented in a wrong / unhelpful way. I tried to mention all the details that i would have problems answering, if the given situation would happen at my table. If  you / others think i should rephrase, please  feel free to point me to some guidelines about how it can be done better.

Comment: Those are just *very* specific situations and with a high degree of *GM Fiat*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, let's see here.

1) Pretty simple; it impacts the square with the wall, doing splash to 8, X, and 4. Nothing's actually *stopping* the splash weapon from exploding in its defined square; instead of striking the intended target, it impacts the wall above their head.

1b) 100% GM Fiat here; if the holes are significant in number and size, the splash weapon could enter one if the GM feels it appropriate (possibly decided by a d100 roll), which might allow for splash at the squares on the other side of the wall. 8, x, and 4 still get splashed, though, since it only deviates one square.

2) Water's got a pretty good surface tension, and it counts as a solid surface for a lot of effects; pertinent to this conversation, we have this tidbit.

> Thrown weapons are ineffective underwater, even when launched from land.

If you're chucking something fragile hard, and it hits the water, it can't continue on past the water's surface, and will, subject to GM Fiat, most likely burst upon striking that square, doing splash as normal. Alchemist Fire, specifically, doesn't work underwater, since it's a nonmagical fire, and would do nothing at all since the water would extinguish it.

2b) Ice is solid. Unless it's exceptionally thin ice, it behaves like normal ground with a couple modifiers (the DC to move across it and the difficult terrain modifier). Splash weapon behaves as normal. Note it deals damage to the ice as well, which may cause it to break or melt.

3) The splash weapon cannot strike a surface to break, so it falls into the hole. It doesn't go *straight* down, so it'll probably impact a wall at some point and burst, but it's not likely to be in any useful manner.

3b) Same as above, but if anything's flying in the square directly above the pit they get splashed.

Edit: Also, splash weapons are all "break on impact" according to the rules for the "Throw Splash Weapon" attack.

> A splash weapon is a ranged weapon that breaks on impact, splashing or scattering its contents over its target and nearby creatures or objects.